# How to check Elasticsearch logs in Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am trying to sync my data from MongoDB in to Amazon Elasticsearch Service using [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic) For some reason, sync is not happening as expected.

I do not see any error from the mongoosastic plugin. Not sure what is failing in AWS Elasticsearch service

Is there any way to get Elasticsearch logs in Amazon Elasticsearch Service?

```
elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

this.es_connection = new elasticsearch.Client("Amazon Elasticsearch Service address");
return this.es_connection.ping({
  requestTimeout: 30000,
  hello: 'elasticsearch'
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!' + JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
    logger.info('All is well in elasticsearch');
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your mongoosastic code and configuration?

Comment: I am trying to index my existing collection as shown in this example(that is I am using the synchronize() ): https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic#indexing-an-existing-collection  This code works fine for me when I try with the latest Elasticsearch installed in an EC2. But does not work with AWS ElasticSearch service.

Comment: I'm interested in 1) how you connect mongoosastic to AWS/ES and 2) whether your cluster on AWS/ES is open to the world or whether there is some security?

Comment: I have updated with the code. The ping call works and I don't get any error.

Comment: How about my second question? Is your cluster open to the world with no security or do you have a specific domain access policy?

Comment: My AWS ES cluster is not open to the world, accessible only to EC2 instance in which I am running my application. I am able to query / ping the AWS ES service from my EC2 application instance

Comment: @Val do you have some clue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot AWS elasticsearch service, you'll need to configure the log shipping to CloudWatch: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/viewing-amazon-elasticsearch-service-error-logs/

Then you will be able to use CloudWatch console in order to view your logs and understand if the issue is in Elasticsearch or is it mongoosastic issue / mapping/ index failures issues.